# Single-signon in android using Active Directory

Tags: java, android, active-directory, accountmanager

I'm trying to implement Single Signon with windows Active Directory can anyone suggest me the best  approach. I've already looked into Kerberos and AccountManger in android or any sample implementation would be useful.

Thanks in advance

Note:I've searched google before posting this question.

Comment: As of 2014-02-14, no mainstream version of android has built in support for Kerberos.  All support for Kerberos would have to be within your app, at which point it is no longer single-sign-on.  If you control the ROM, you can add support as listed https://github.com/cconlon/kerberos-android-ndk, but that is not for the fainthearted...

Comment: There is now a commercial solution: https://www.hypergate.com

Answer (score 1):

Check the Azure Active Directory Authentication Library for Android (ADAL)
https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-android

Comment: this library connect in a new page asking to enter credentials, not with single click authentication